# How to install couchdb on mac osx 10.6

Tags: macos, couchdb

I'm trying to install CouchDB on my mac, running snow leopard 10.6. I installed Xcode, MacPorts, and then followed the instructions here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX

It all worked fine until I tried to visit the web interface: http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/index.html

Google chrome said "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:5984"

I tried connecting using telnet in bash and it said connection refused. Can somebody shed some light with some suggestions or perhaps and idiot-proof walkthrough?

Answer (score 2):

Just install Homebrew https://github.com/include/homebrew , then:

$ brew install couchdb

have fun

Answer (score 1):

With homebrew, you have to do this after the installation :

Edit the key UserName in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.apache.couchdb.plist then make sure the user owns these folders :

- /usr/local/var/log/couchdb/
- /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb/
- /usr/local/etc/couchdb/

or simply use couchdbx !

Answer (score 0):

I struggled the same thing for a couple of days.  I finally the following link, which provides it as a simple mac app (download CounchOne), with GUI tool packaged for you. You don't have to deal with permission and dependency.

http://www.couch.io/get